# #Antd# How can I bind self-made component with Form.item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to use my component like this

```js
<Form.item>
  <MyComponent />
</Form.item>
```

I can't pass the defaultValue to MyComponent and the Form can't get the value from MyComponent when I hit the submit button. 
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using a default value you can use `initialValues` from antd's `Form` together with the in `Form.Item` defined `name`.

E.g.:

```
<Form
  {...layout}
  name="basic"
  initialValues={{
    myComponent: "IntialTestValue"
  }}
  onFinish={onFinish}
  onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
>
  <Form.Item
    label="MyComponent"
    name="myComponent"
```

To use custom or third party component you need bind your component to a `value` and `onChange`.

E.g.:

```
const MyComponent = ({ value = {}, onChange }) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(value);

  const onInputChange = e => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
    onChange(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Input defaultValue={value} value={inputValue} onChange={onInputChange} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Here is a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-lehmann-p6kpg).

Another good example can be found int [antd Form docs](https://ant.design/components/form/?locale=en-US#components-form-demo-customized-form-controls): [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/e9bwm)